# How to return multiple results on the same line (jQuery help)

Tags: jquery, string

I know the title of this question isn't very helpful as I'm uncertain how to ask the question. But will tell you what I am trying to achieve.

Please see my example as it will be easier to explain.

I am recording the data questionid and the data answerid which outputs 1~1 or 1~2 (in the console) which is what I want, but in the instance that both answers are selected (.active) I want to return the query as 1~1;1~2 on the same line in the console (for now). But at the moment when I select both, it just outputs them in the console separately.

Hope you can help and hope my question makes sense.

Thanks.

```js
$('.answer').on('click', function(event) {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    var questionid = $(".question").data("questionid");
    var answerid = $(".answer.active").data("answerid");
    //console.log("questionid " + questionid);
   //console.log("answerid " + answerid);
    var query = questionid + "~" + answerid;
    console.log(query)
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="question" data-questionid="1">Question 1</div>
<div class="answer" data-answerid="1">Answer 1</div>
<div class="answer" data-answerid="2">Answer 2</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$(".answer.active")` returns multiple elements, so you have to loop with `each`.

```js
$('.answer').on('click', function(event) {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    var questionid = $(".question").data("questionid");
    var query = '';
    $(".answer.active").each(function(){
     var answerid = $(this).data("answerid");
     query = query + ";" + questionid + "~" + answerid;
    });
    if (query.substring(0, 1) == ';') { 
      query = query.substring(1);
   }

    console.log(query)
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="question" data-questionid="1">Question 1</div>
<div class="answer" data-answerid="1">Answer 1</div>
<div class="answer" data-answerid="2">Answer 2</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make another function which is responsible for iterating over all active elements and let your current function just toggle the class.

```
$('.answer').on('click', function(event) {
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
  logActives();
}

function logActives(){
var query = "";
$(".answer.active").each(function(){
  query += $(this).data("questionid")+"~"+$(this).data("answerid")+";";
});
console.log(query);
```